# See Queue items in Pydev debug

Tags: python, debugging, queue, pydev

Is it possible, and how, to see the items in a [`Queue`](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) instance while debugging in [PyDev](http://pydev.org/), without popping them out via the interactive console?
Best would be via the *Expressions* view of course as that would update while stepping the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `q.queue` attribute to access the underlying sequence:

```
>>> q = Queue()
>>> q.put(1)
>>> q.queue
deque([1])
```